# Add new line for column description in SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form

Is it possible when creating lists in SharePoint to have the decriptions of the list on more lines?

[image]

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I would much rather it looked like this:

1 Meget Lille
2 Lille
3 Moderat
4 Stort
5 Meget stort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it's not possible, SharePoint is rendering description as plain text using `<div>{Your description}</div>`. Here only possible way to inject your css using **SPFx extension** and applying `while-space:pre` in this div

[image]

[image]

Below are some articles which can help you to inject your custom **CSS** using SPFx exntesion.

- https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-online-how-to-inject-custom-css-in-modern-sites/
- https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

> Note
>
> Keep in mind that Microsoft may change page elements and styles at any
> time, rendering your custom CSS useless. It is preferrable to use
> well-known HTML element placeholders.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation. :)